# Code stuck in loop

Tags: java

I made a script that takes a picture, starts from the top left corner (a white pixel in the case of my test image), and proceeds to go through the image like a magic wand tool, selecting the pixels that are of a similar enough color.

But the script doesn't finish executing even after going through the loop more times than there are pixels in the image.

The test image is roughly 160K pixels. `Tools.loadImage()` is a self-written method. I've used it elsewhere, it most probably works. The following is not the entirety of my code, but the part that seemed relevant to the problem.

```
static int[][][] image;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    image = Tools.loadImage(path1);

    int height = image.length;
    int width = image[0].length;
    int[][][] newImage = new int[height][width][4];

    ArrayList<Integer> toCheck = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> checked = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int[] baseColor = image[0][0];
    toCheck.add(0);

    while (!toCheck.isEmpty()) {
        i++;
        int coords = toCheck.get(0);
        int x = coords % width;
        int y = coords / width;

        if (check(x, y, baseColor, 128)) {
            coords = y * width + x - 1;
            if (x > 0 && !(checked.contains(coords) || toCheck.contains(coords))) {
                toCheck.add(coords);
            }
            coords = y * width + x + 1;
            if (x < width - 1 && !(checked.contains(coords) || toCheck.contains(coords))) {
                toCheck.add(coords);
            }
            coords = (y - 1) * width + x;
            if (y > 0 && !(checked.contains(coords) || toCheck.contains(coords))) {
                toCheck.add(coords);
            }
            coords = (y + 1) * width + x;
            if (y < height - 1 && !(checked.contains(coords) || toCheck.contains(coords))) {
                toCheck.add(coords);
            }
        }

        checked.add(coords);
        toCheck.remove(0);
    }
}

static boolean check(int x, int y, int[] color, int threshold) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(image[y][x][i] - color[i]) > threshold) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

PS. If you feel like pointing out obvious ways to make this loop faster, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: `ArrayList#contains()` works in `O(n)` time so you can use there `HashSet` which will be more optimal way to check entry of the coordinates.

Comment: Okay, woah, that improved speed about a thousand times, thank you. Still stuck in that loop though.

Comment: @nhouser9 because OP doesn't want to check every single pixel.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem a BitSet would be a better choice then.

Comment: Yup, a BitSet would be even better.

Comment: Please read (and follow) the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The add to checked is in the wrong place.

```
while (!toCheck.isEmpty()) {
    i++;
    int coords = toCheck.get(0);
    checked.add(coords);        // important
    toCheck.remove(0);          // might as well do this here too
    int x = coords % width;
    int y = coords / width;
```

coords is overwritted repeatedly in the loop, and thus the current pixel is not added but the last of the four neighbours. Thus some condition fails later and some wrong pixel is added toCheck.

Comment: *sigh* It's always the simple things that you somehow overlook every time you go over your code.
Thank you very much, I've been agonizing over this for a few hours now.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `coords` in the body of the loop, so at the end of each iteration you're marking the wrong pixel.  It's perfectly safe to move the marking immediately after popping the next point off `toCheck`.

Perfomance-wise, consider using a `BitSet` for `checked` (as per @JB Nizet's suggestion,) and an `ArrayDeque` for `toCheck`.

Comment: Why not use a `BitSet` for both `checked` and `toCheck`?

Comment: You need to be able to obtain the next point from `toCheck` quickly.  `BitSet` does have a method for that, but it will take a linear search through the set, which you probably want to avoid.  An `ArrayDeque` will serve it in constant time, and at the same time will spare you of the shifting of the array that would take place with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: OK, fair enough.